# How to provide a widget with my app?

Tags: android, widget

I have an android app, which is working well. I would like to provide a widget with this app for the next version.

I saw many tutorials to create an activity launching the widget directly. However my wish would be to add my widget to the widget list of the phone that you add manually in addition of the normal app I already have.

My widget is already ready to use ( the layout, the different parameters, the xml file ) but I was not able yet to find a way to just provide the widget in addition of my application.

Could you show me an example or the way to achieve that? As an example, I already follow those tutorials:

[Link 1](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-essentials-enhancing-your-applications-with-app-widgets--mobile-6245)

[Link 2](http://www.androidauthority.com/create-simple-android-widget-608975/)

[Link 3](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html)

Facebook or linkedIn provide those kind of widget as well, as an example.

Comment: To the people who downvote me, I am not asking for an already made solution but for the technical way to provide a widget with an app. I didn't find any tutorials for that, while all I was wanting was to add a widget to the widget list of my phone without bothering the normal use of my app.